# azure VM A1 stuck at Undoing changes

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I was working on my azure VM today (BASIC, A1 (1core, 1.75GB memory)), after i was prompted to restart the VM for windows updates. it was down for an full hour. When i was able to connect back to it. this message appeard:

Since i dont have 10 reputation, this is the link to the error my VM gives me.
https://i.gyazo.com/f7a8e14e4120c1ed8340077adf430926.png

At this point. i cant  do anything to the VM because of the risk of losing data. But i also dont know if this ever goes away (its already 2 hour like this.)

If anyone could inform me on whats going on or want to help me. Help is much apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found, There was a problem at the update service right at the moment i was going to update the VM. After a few tweets i managed to fix it with them.